# Exporting map function into other file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Is it possible to export the function inside the orders.map which is 'order' and import it on the other JS file with function inside? I am getting an error order is not defined. Thank you

```
main.js

     const getReport = async function() {
      const jsonlUrl = 'https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/xxxxx'
      const res = await fetch(jsonlUrl);
      const orders = await res.json();

      const orderlines = orders.map(order => ({

       order_id: order.order_id,

      customer_name: getName()

      }));

---

function.js

const getName = function() {
const customerName = order.customer_name
 return customerName
}
```

Comment: What is 'the other JS file'?  That is not clear.

Comment: hello @jhenderson2099, i've updated the codes. thank you

Comment: This has been resolved. I did
```
function.js

const getName = function(order) {
const customerName = order.customer_name
 return customerName
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved: 
Passed the parameter into function call

```
main.js
     const getReport = async function() {
      const jsonlUrl = 'https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/xxxxx'
      const res = await fetch(jsonlUrl);
      const orders = await res.json();

      const orderlines = orders.map(order => ({

       order_id: order.order_id,

      customer_name: getName(order)

      }));
```

I added the parameter on the function getName

```
function.js
const getName = function(order) { 
const customerName = order.customer_name 
return customerName 
}
```